# Error "pip: orden no encontrada"

Tags: python, pip

Mi problema es el siguiente:

> Cannot start QR scanner.The zbar package is not available. On Linux, try 'sudo pip install zbar'

Al teclear `sudo pip install zbar` me aparece el mensaje:

> pip: orden no encontrada

Comment: y tenes instalado pip?

Comment: ¿como puedo saberlo?

Comment: hay que ver si tu distribucion de linux instalo python e instalo pip.. pip es el obtenedor de paquetes de python....

Comment: ¿cómo puedo saber si mi distribución de linux instaló python?

Comment: la mayoria de las distribuciones lo tienen.. deberias verificar la documentacion de la distribucion...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lo primero que necesitamos conocer es el sistema operativo y versión de la máquina en la que tienes este problema. Con esa información podremos ofrecerte las instrucciones para instalar `pip`.

Comment: y que tal si haces `pip3 install ****`

Comment: Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Escritorio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Escritorio

Comment: Para saber si tienes instalado Python, puedes correr `which python3`. Lo mismo para pip (`which pip`). Si alguno de los dos no te da la ubicación del binario, instalalo con tu administrador de paquetes. Sea el caso de que todo está instalado, te recomiendo correr `python3 -m pip install paquete --user`, es lo que funciona para mí.

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar pip puedes usar los siguientes comandos.

Para python 2

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Para python 3

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Si luego de instalar sigue sin reconocer puede acceder a pip por medio del siguiente comando

```
python -m pip install <paquete>
```

Para el caso especifico de `zbar` la instalación usando pip causa problemas. Por ello puedes usar los siguientes comandos.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-zbar libzbar-dev python3-qrtools
```

Comment: 'python3 -m pip install zbar'
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting zbar
  Using cached zbar-0.10.tar.bz2 (16 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: zbar
  Building wheel for zbar (setup.py) ... error

Comment: **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-bygvqk6z
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/
  Complete output (13 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build**

Comment: **  running build_ext
  building 'zbar' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/zbarmodule.o
  In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:
**

Comment: **  zbarmodule.h:26:10: fatal error: zbar.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
     26 | #include <zbar.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for zbar**

Comment: Running setup.py clean for zbar
Failed to build zbar
Installing collected packages: zbar
    Running setup.py install for zbar ... error

Comment: **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"';**

Comment: **__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6m6fxfrr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/victor/.local/include/python3.8/zbar
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/
    Complete output (13 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
**

Comment: **building 'zbar' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c zbarmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/zbarmodule.o
    In file included from zbarmodule.c:24:**

Comment: **zbarmodule.h:26:10: fatal error: zbar.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
       26 | #include <zbar.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------**

Comment: **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4f5wz3q1/zbar/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();**

Comment: **exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-6m6fxfrr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/victor/.local/include/python3.8/zbar Check the logs for full command output.**

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, agregando el caso especifico de la libreria que necesitas

Comment: $ pip install pyngrok Orden «pip» no encontrada, pero hay 18 similares. como soluciono en este caso

Answer (score 1):

Yo tenía el mismo error, asi que lo que hice fue cambiar el comando $sudo pip install --- por $sudo pip3 install ---

Antes de ejecutar este comando instalé pip3 con $sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip

Saludos